# boto3 publish to topic with name

Tags: boto3, amazon-sns

How do I publish to a topic by using its name than the arn. And I dont see any guide on how to in the documentation. Currently the only way to access a topic is thorugh the arn.

I use a deployment script like serverless to create all my lambda's and topics and have friendly names.

The only way for me to access a topic by name is by

```
import boto3
sns = boto3.client('sns')
topics = sns.list_topics()
topic_arn = // search for topic with name in arns stored in topics
topic_arn.publish()
```

This approach seems inefficient and it would be good to access a topic directly by name, or is there a solution to this?

Answer (score 4):

You don't have to search through topics to find the ARN, just create it yourself (Python 3):

```
aws_region = 'us-west-1' # or whatever you like
aws_account_id = '123456789012' # replace with your real account ID via some secure mechanism
topic_name = 'FriendlySNSTopicName' # replace as needed
topic_arn = f"arn:aws:sns:{aws_region}:{aws_account_id}:{topic_name}"
```

Also note that your supplied code won't work. You are creating a low-level client, but using the resource style for your `publish()` call.